# Is Google Drive suitable for use as a corporate file server

Tags: google-drive, cloud-storage, file-server

We have been using Google apps for a while and I was wondering if I could/should migrate the our corporate file servers over to use Google Drive? as this would mean all my users will have access to anything they need from any location.

I know that I would need to also have a robust backup plan in place, I was just wondering if anyone had done this and what the downsides issues might be.

Comment: I should add this is a SME, and the data stored will not be any that requires extra controls e.g. financial, medical etc

Comment: checkout Drobo - http://www.drobo.com/ - they have units that will meet whatever your budget/needs are from real basic units to really advanced stuff. Its basically a drop-in NAS for your business. You just supply the drives, and it takes care of the rest. Real simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very situation based question. If you are a large to medium sized company then you should already have a file-server. If your a small company however then it also depends on what you do. Sensitive information (Social security, Medical, important records, ect.) should never be stored in the cloud. That information should be stored on a local file server. Also you shouldn't need a robust backup plan. Google is a well established extremely large and powerful company. The chances of google's whole operation going down are slim to none. Saying this however I do not mean you should have no backup. I don't think non-sensitive information is any problem though however.

Other problems- Depending on what files your putting on your google drive will determine how useful it will be. If your trying to store videos (example not sure how well that works). it may not work as well as another service such as Drop Box.

Comment: The reason I mentioned backup is that Google drive doest hold a incremental backup of file, and if a user deletes a file its gone..

Comment: Exactly. Also I'd use a compressed version of the information that way IF in the unlikely chance that an EMP hits everywhere on earth except where you're located and somehow destroys the servers I'm sure google has that are protected against this then you can uncompress the information and you don't lose it.

Comment: Encrypt your business data before sending it to the cloud! This unfortunately forces GCloud or Dropbox to re-sync the entire binary blob, however it prevents GCloud, Dropbox or other from intentionally/unintentionally leaking your sensitive business data! Check out TrueCrypt (google it)

Comment: @SnakeDoc That is true. Very good idea if the google apps don't save the information in the drive. If not I highly recommend you do this.

Answer (score 1):

No, in the event of a financial audit or legal investigation, you may be required to hand over all the information your users store. For other legal reasons you may be required BY LAW to maintain exclusive control of that data at all times.

Check out "self hosted cloud" options such as

1. OwnCloud
2. SparkleShare
3. SyncBlaze

I'm no lawyer, but some user data in the enterprise is legally proteted by law in such a way that you are prevented from using googledrive and other solutions to ensure nobody else could potentially access that information.